# Server returned Http Response code : 707

Tags: java

While i am going to hit the Client URL to check the charging of a particular appliances I am getting the error as server returned HTTP response code :707 for the URL : in Java
Why I am getting this response code?

Comment: it is not a standard response code. May be custom added by the webmaster.

Comment: is there a  odd chance of  forwarding System error code 707,by the server .
generally,
System error code 707 means "{Partial Data Received} The network transport returned partial data to its client. The remaining data will be sent later." This error code may also display as "ERROR_RECEIVE_PARTIAL" or as the value 0x2C3.

Comment: It's not standard and it's not (regrettably) captured in the [extended 7XX spec](https://github.com/joho/7XX-rfc), either.   It's likely custom.

Comment: How do the appliances connect to the network? Any chance it's a mobile/cellular connection?

Answer (score 2):

`707 webmaster on vacation` ?

It's not an official HTTP Status Code. You sure it's HTTP response code, not a custom system status code?

See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html